# How to print 0xff byte in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to `print` some `0xff` bytes using **Python 3.5.2** to pipe them into another program. I have a simple C program which reads from `stdin` and prints each char in hex:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main () {
    char *buffer = malloc(0x100);
    fgets(buffer, 0x100, stdin);
    for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != 0; printf("%x ", buffer[i++]));
}
```

If I echo `0xff` byte and pipe it into my program, chars are displayed as expected (`a` is because of newline):

```
# echo -e "\xff\xff\xff\xff" | ./print-chars
ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff a
```

I can also do it with Perl:

```
# perl -e 'print "\xff\xff\xff\xff"' | ./print-chars
ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
```

But when I try it in python, the result is different:

```
 # python -c 'print("\xff\xff\xff\xff")' | ./print-chars
ffffffc3 ffffffbf ffffffc3 ffffffbf ffffffc3 ffffffbf ffffffc3 fffffbf a
```

My questions:

- Why does Python print `0xc3` and `0xb3` bytes instead of `0xff`?
- What is the proper way of printing `0xff` using Python (I want to achieve the same result as with echo or Perl)?

Comment: Thank you, `sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"\xff\xff\xff\xff")` works perfectly

Comment: As an aside: Declare `buffer` as `unsigned char *buffer` to avoid the erroneous leading `ffffff`-s.

Comment: @duskwuff: thank you for suggestion, I only included this code to demonstrate what the output of Python's `print` is, it is not actual code that I use anywhere

Comment: What you're seeing is the result of encoding: `'\xff\xff\xff\xff'.encode()` returns `b'\xc3\xbf\xc3\xbf\xc3\xbf\xc3\xbf'`. The last `a` corresponds to the newline character.

Answer (score -1):

One of the way is use [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to pack a values into binary string:

```
import struct
value = 0xFF
s = struct.pack('B', value)
print(s)
list_of_values = [255]*4
s = struct.pack('4B', *list_of_values)
print(s)
```

will give next output:

```
b'\xff'
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

Comment: ... which is the same as the output of `print(bytes([255] * 4))`, which when piped into OP's C program becomes `62 27 5c 78 66 66 5c 78 66 66 5c 78 66 66 5c 78 66 66 27 a`.